# Having @2x image assets without @1x assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I'm working on an app which has a lot of graphics.  The app is targeting iPhones with iOS 7+, so all of the devices that support it have retina displays.  I'm adding only @2x and @3x graphics, because @1x graphics are never going to be used, and I don't want the size of the bundle to grow more than it has to.

I load most of the images programmatically:

```
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn"]];
```

This is supposed to load `ButtonOn@2x.jpg` for @2x displays and `ButtonOn@3x.jpg` for iPhone 6 plus.

However, I noticed this behavior:

- iPhone 6 Plus does load the @3x image.
- But the other iPhones – 4, 4s, 5s and 6, do not load the @2x.
- I can force it to load the @2x image by using the graphics full name, for instance: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn@2x.jpg"]`, but this defeats the purpose of the naming convention, and it also forces me to detect the screen density by myself.

Is there a way to have @2x and @3x images without @1x ones?

**UPDATE:** the problem had nothing to do with the screen density.  The problem was that, since I am using JPG graphics instead than PNG ones, Xcode can't find them unless I use the file's full name extension.  Maybe this is a bug.

Comment: You need 1x images when your app runs on the iPad 2.

Comment: The bug is in not listening to what you're being told...

Comment: I'm listening, but I'm also using an assets catalog.

Comment: You _have_ an asset catalog, but that does not mean you are _using_ it. If you give a name in `imageNamed:` that doesn't match the name of any image set in your asset catalog, the runtime dives into the app bundle _instead_. And that's what it has been doing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with omitting the 1x image, and indeed it is usual to do so for an iPhone-only app (as there are no single-resolution iPhone devices that will run this system). The problem is your code. In particular, this line is wrong:

```
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn"]];
```

You have two choices:

- This is a *.jpg* file, so say so:

  ```
  [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn.jpg"]];
  ```
- Even better, just leave it the way you have it, and use an asset catalog instead of individual files with the funny `@2x` names.

**EDIT**: Based on your comments and the details in your question, I'd have to say that you are deeply confused about whether or not you are using an asset catalog. You say that you are, but in that case, saying `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn@2x.jpg"]` would not work — and you say that it does work. So clearly you still have this file sitting at the top level of your app bundle. That's part of your problem. You need to delete these image files from the app bundle and rely *solely* on the asset catalog.

Comment: I'm using an assets catalog.  2x images won't load unless I also add 1x images.

Comment: "2x images won't load unless I also add 1x images" That's just not true. I do this all the time. If you are using an asset catalog, then the name `@"ButtonOn@2x.jpg"` should not work at all. I would have to suggest that you _think_ you are using an asset catalog but perhaps you are not. Clearly you still have named image files still sitting in your app bundle. You need to delete these. I've modified my answer to mention this.

Comment: I swear I'm using the assets catalog only =P.  I kept the naming convention because if you drag the images into the assets catalog with the naming convention, Xcode automatically puts them in the right screen density.  I noticed the problem is not the one I described.  The real problem is that images are not loaded unless I add the .jpg extension... I don't know if that has something to do with the fact that they are not PNG's.

Comment: "The real problem is that images are not loaded unless I add the .jpg extension" Then either you are not using an asset catalog or you have given the image set the wrong name. Trust me on this one.

Comment: The naming was right and it was an asset catalog... but I just figured it out.  I tried with PNG files instead than JPG's and it worked properly.  Apparently, when you use JPG files you have to include the file's extension: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonOn.jpg"]`, otherwise it won't find it.

Comment: I said that in my answer. Did you notice that? That was my _first answer_. See it? - But that is when it is _not_ in an asset catalog. You are still confused about where these images are coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94011/discussion-between-calvillo-and-matt).

Comment: Let's not. I answered the question and I answered it _correctly_.

Comment: I'm sorry Matt, I didn't mean tu upset you.  Indeed, you mentioned including .jpg.  However, you also mentioned that I should use an asset catalog, which I am currently using, and I don't have the files anywhere else in my bundle.  So I believe this might be an assets catalog bug.  I also believe your answer is only half right.

Comment: You _do_ have the files in your bundle. If you didn't, `imageNamed:@"ButtonOn@2x.jpg"` would not have worked. Think about it. That's not the name of an image set in your asset catalog, so where is the image coming from??? There is only one possible answer.

Comment: It's coming from the assets catalog.  If you drag an image named `ButtonOn@2x.jpg` to the asset catalog it creates an entry for `ButtonOn` and places the image in the 2x version.  I'm pretty sure the files are not anywhere else in my bundle.

Comment: "If you drag an image named ButtonOn@2x.jpg to the asset catalog it creates an entry for ButtonOn and places the image in the 2x version" That may be true, but you would then _not_ be able to refer to it as `imageNamed:@"ButtonOn@2x.jpg"`. So the files _are_ elsewhere in your bundle; otherwise, that line would not work, and you say it _does_ work. If you think about this fact and about my answer, you will find that my answer completely covers the situation.

Comment: After one adds the image to the assets catalog in that way, if one checks the project's files, one would find an `Images.xcassets` folder that contains a `ButtonOn.imageset` folder, which in turn contains a `Contents.json` file and a `ButtonOn@2x.jpg` file.  Xcode does not rename the file, that's why the code is able to find it.

Comment: No, you're wrong. The runtime doesn't look in there when you call `imageNamed:`. The original name of the image, after you put it into the asset catalog, is completely irrelevant. I keep telling you this, but you keep not believing me.